# ramdajs recursion one nested JSON

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

```
const arr = [1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9],10]]];
```

Lets say we have a nested array like above. Is there a specific deep recursion method?

Instead of calling the same function in function or iteratively looping; is there any deepMap function which iterates over all nested items?

Something traverses the object tree entirely.

```
R.deepMap(function(e){
   console.log(e)
});
//1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: what do you wish to achieve ?

Comment: @marvel308 updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often easier to break it down into smaller bits of functionality, in this case flattening a deeply nested array, and then mapping over it.

```
const deepMap = f => R.pipe(flatten, map(f))

deepMap(R.inc)(arr)
// -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: It's unclear from the question whether this is important or not, but this solution does not retain the initial nesting nesting structure.  If it's unimportant, than this is a much better solution than my suggestion. But it's not that difficult to retain the structure.

Comment: True, I assumed because the output was comma delimited they meant a flat array, although I agree it's ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such a thing built into Ramda.  (I don't know quite how we'd type the input.)  But it's easy enough to write your own:

```
const arr = [1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9],10]]]

const deepMap = (fn, xs) => map(x => is(Array, x) ? deepMap(fn, x) : fn(x), xs)

deepMap(n => n * n, arr) //=> [1, 4, [9, 16, 25, [36, 49, [64, 81], 100]]]
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20arr%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C%5B3%2C4%2C5%2C%5B6%2C7%2C%5B8%2C9%5D%2C10%5D%5D%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20deepMap%20%3D%20%28fn%2C%20xs%29%20%3D%3E%20map%28x%20%3D%3E%20is%28Array%2C%20x%29%20%3F%20deepMap%28fn%2C%20x%29%20%3A%20fn%28x%29%2C%20xs%29%0A%0AdeepMap%28n%20%3D%3E%20n%20%2A%20n%2C%20arr%29)**

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```js
const arr = [1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9],10]]];

function flatten(arr){
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
        if(b instanceof Array)
            a = a.concat(flatten(b));
        else
            a.push(b);
        return a;
    }, []);
}

console.log(flatten(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [R.flatten](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten) method to flat your nested array in one array.

Then  use [R.forEach](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#forEach) method to apply a function on all the new array items.

***Ex:***

```js
const arr = [1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9],10]]];

R.forEach(function (e) {
  console.log(e);
}, R.flatten(arr))
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ramda/latest/ramda.min.js"></script>
```